# Dll of R code or .R file

Tags: c++, c, r, dll, rcpp

I am having code1.R code2.R and code3.R. I would like to pass these functions to somebody as DLL such that he can execute these codes without being able to look inside the code.

How can I make DLL of .R files?

I tried various means but unable to do so far.

Comment: what IDE/Compiler you are using ?

Comment: Hiding your code is against the open source philosophy of R. Hence R provides no mechanismes to hide your code.

Comment: You can use [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) and have your R functions as C++ strings in separate functions in the C++ codebase. You can then compile the C++ to a shared library and let your users call them that way. It won't obfuscate it that much (a simple `strings` on linux/mac/bsd will reveal the function code), but on Windows it might be just enough for your needs.

Comment: Rtools, the standard R development tools distribution for Windows, includes strings.  If you really want to hide it then R is probably not your best choice.

Comment: @hrbrmstr sure it makes it harder. but at the end of the day R code has to be parsed and evaluated by R. If you have your R code as a C++ string, you are still linking against R, and someone properly skilled can definitely access the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

R is interpreted, not compiled. There might be ways to obfuscate your code, but R needs to be able to parse it if you want it to evaluate it.

You could implement your logic in a compiled language (e.g. C or C++), embed that code in a package and then give a binary version of the package to your client.

You could also set up some R server and only give access certain entry point to your client.

But there's no way to "compile" R code.

Comment: Well, there is the `compiler` package, but it doesn't do what the OP wants.